# Webpacker error in rails 7 , <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker

I've been having this issue some time since I've started this course, however only now it became a problem.

I'm fairly new to rails and I have this issue with webpacker:

[webpacker error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zORma.png)

The problem is with the <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>  If I simply delete it, there is no problem and everything is working as it should, however as expected JavaScript is not included to file.

So far I've spend some time on fixing error and tried those solutions:

->  Reinstalling webpacker

-> Reinstalling RoR and all gems

-> trying to change application.js  path, to make sure rails sees it

-> Trying to run a Completly new RoR project - had the same error

-> Tried to use some work-around code for <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> , also with no succsess

- Ive tried all solutions that mentioned above on rails 6.06 and on rails 7.0.4

Im using Rails 7.0.4 , ruby 3.1.2 and webpacker 4.0, on windows 10

I really hope someone will help me out w this. I can even paypal if ud make it work lol

PS. Sorry for my grammar, except RoR I'm also learning English :)

Below all the files and info that might be needed:

CONSOLE ERROR

[console err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DMV9.png)

GEMFILE

```
> source 'https://rubygems.org'
> git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
> 
> ruby '3.1.2'
> 
> Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
> gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.4'
> Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
> gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
> Use Puma as the app server
> gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
> changed by mua
> gem 'tzinfo-data'
> 
> Use SCSS for stylesheets
> gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
> Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
> gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
> Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
> gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
> Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
> gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
> Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
> gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
> Use Active Model has_secure_password
> gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
> gem 'psych', '< 4'
> Use Active Storage varianti
> gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
> 
> Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
> gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
> 
> group :development, :test do
> Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
> gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
> end
> 
> group :development do
> Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
> gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
> end
> 
> group :test do
> Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
> gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
> gem 'selenium-webdriver'
> Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
> gem 'webdrivers'
> end
> 
> Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
> gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

APPLICATION JS

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
import "bootstrap"
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "alpha_blog",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```